# PHP datetime() today at 12pm

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to generate a datetime - fine for hardcoded dates

```
 $start  = new DateTime('2015-08-14 12:00:00');
```

but I want to try and make it the today at 12:00.

```
$start  = new DateTime('Y-m-d 12:00:00');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean it should work simply

```
$date = new DateTime('12:00:00');
```

The `DateTime` parameter has to be by [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) `date/time`, of one them. `12:00:00` is valid `time`.